# Make arbitrary url as homepage

Tags: django

I have such a `urls.py` configuration in project repository "forum"

```
# Project url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^$", views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^article/', include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
]
```

and with `article/urls.py` as

```
#Article app's url config
urlpatterns = [
    # show the article list
    url(r"^list/(?P<block_id>\d+)$", views.article_list, name="article_list"),
```

I attempt to take "^article/list/1$" as home page instead of "views.index".

How to make it redirect to `"^article/list/1$"` when I issue request "127.0.0.1:8000"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect from your views.index. In your views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    return redirect('article:article_list')
```

which should take you to article/list. You can include that block_id parameter in the redirect function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
redirect(reverse('article:article_list', kwargs={'block_id':2}))
```

and make sure to add kwargs in function like this

```
article_list(request,**kwargs):
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to this to debug your article page.
You have two ways of doing this.

1. Either redirect your index view to article view

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    def index(request):
        #We force a redirect to article_list view, and we pass arguments.
        #Notice it has to come first.
        redirect ("article_list", article_list_argument_view=1)
        #it will redirect to localhost:8000/article/list/1
        '''
        Your  Home page code.
        '''
```

2. Put the url directly before the include

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r"^$", views.index, name="index"),

    #The order is important.
    url(r'^article/list/1$', "article_list",     {'article_list_argument_view':1})

    url(r'^article/', include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
    ]
```